# How to pause the other instructions until the dialog message is closed

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, toast

Hi I have a question on AlertDialog / Toast . 
When a user clicks on a button , just a message showing "You are right " should be displayed for 1 seconds. When I implement this using toast/alertdialog it executes this but starts the next instruction in the onclick method before the dailog is turned off. How do I fix this?

Comment: This is an awesome question as I have noticed this myself. You would think Android would "wait" for the response, but instead your program continues to execute even though it's waiting on a response.

Comment: sleep the thread for a sometime while the dialog dismisses.

Comment: Sleeping the UI thread would cause it to not respond when the user clicks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you are using a toast, postpone a task for the time the toast is being displayed using  [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html).

When using a dialog, implement an [onClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#setOnDismissListener%28android.content.DialogInterface.OnDismissListener%29) for the "Okey" button.

Comment: There wouldn't be any problem for dialog because it will pause until the user clicks..but for toast to display just a message , it doesn't wait on anything and hence continues executing the next instruction which is undesirable..pausing using a thread causes it be unresponsive after the dialog.. how is different using a handler,,could you explain with a code snippet ?

Answer (score 2):

## Here is how I did it using Handler object ---

public class ToastActivity extends Activity{

```
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main); 
    Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    for(int i=10;i>=1;i--)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, ""+i, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){public void run(){
    LinearLayout t=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.l);   //This task is delayed by 21 sec.
            t.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
        }
    }, 21000);           
}
```

}

Statements after toast are executed after toast has disappeared.

Comment: Because a toast of length short shows for 2 seconds, it's necessary that the minimum wait time is about 20000ms, so waiting 21000ms is some how hardcoded but it's the right thing.

Answer (score 0):

What I have had to do, is put any code that comes after the AlertDialog, in the corresponding  listener. For example if you have a bunch of code after an alert dialog, that you only want to execute based on some response, move that code into another method. Then, in either your positiveButton listener (or negative button listener), add the call to the corresponding method you just created. Or you could just cram it all in the listener, but that makes the code less manageable.

Comment: no there is no respnse..the dialog should appear and go before the other statements are executed which is not listening to any respnse